# Is it really necessary to bump minor edits on the main page?

Tags: discussion

There were around 6 posts which were tagged with [untagged](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). So I thought it might be a good idea to tag them with something useful. This turned out to be a big mistake as now I have taken over the front page with these minor edits. I didn't go in and edit these posts, I just used the in-line 'retag' functionality.

So two things:

- Should these trivial/maintenance edits really bump the questions up to the top of the active page?
- Should it really show my name as the last active user? Sure, I did make a change, but it is hardly worth broadcasting to the world about this update.

Comment: Is difficult to the system choose what is really unnecessary. Sometimes even a minor change can turn the meaning in another direction. Maybe we need an option to bump or not. ;)

Comment: Could just chuck those edits in the review queue.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the small edit changes a meaning of a question - it shouldn't be revived back to main page unless new answer gets posted.

It already got it's chance to be on a main page. Now other questions should be given the right. I doubt be need the same stuff pop over and over again just because two people play small edit war there or someone decided to add a tag.

It also is discouraging for editors who know about this, as they might not want some very old, meaningless and already answered questions pop on the main page just because they did minor technical change related to the housekeeping. Nothing should discourage such actions, as we need people like row1 to fix old, rusty questions. Otherwise in 2 years time we'll end up under huge pile of mess.